# Jump statement offset or displacement?

Tags: loops, assembly, conditional-statements, x86-16, transfer

Do the 8086 conditional and unconditional jumps have signed displacement (is it 8 bit or 16 bit?) from the current instruction or do they specify the offset from the code segment register to the label?

e.g, when I write:

```
label1: 
..
..
jmp label1 (unconditional)
```

Will this *label1* be replaced by signed displacement or offset from code segment?

```
cmp ex, 0
je label2 ( conditional)
```

Will this *label2* be replaced by signed displacement or offset from code segment?

Also, when I use the `loop` instruction as below:

```
loop1:
..
..
loop loop1
```

Will this *loop1* will be replaced by signed displacement (is it 8 bit or 16 bit?) or offset from code segment?

Comment: Why don't you consult the instruction set reference, which clearly answers these questions?

Answer (score 0):

In all of these cases the label used will be replaced by a signed offset from the rear of the current instruction. So **nothing to do with the start of the code segment**.

The unconditional jump `jmp label1` comes in two flavors:

- using a 8-bit signed offset
- using a 16-bit signed offset

The conditional jump `je label2` and the looping instruction `loop loop1` only use a 8-bit signed offset. (This is true on 8086. Later processors gave the conditional jumps also 16-bit signed offsets.)